# How to pass some data to next webpack loader

Tags: webpack, loader

I'm trying to write some chained loaders for [BEM metodology](https://en.bem.info/).
Here is a part of webpack config.

```
  entry: './src/pages/index.bemjson.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
   rules: [
     {
         test: /\.bemjson\.js$/,
         loader: 'bh-loader!bemdeps-loader!bemdecl-loader!bemjson-loader'
     }
   ]
```

Result of first loader (bemjson-loader) required later in other loaders (bemdecl-loader and bh-loader).

**What is correct way to pass data thru such loaders pipe?**

Documentation says that loaders should be simple (prefer such chaining over single complicated loader). 
It seems that i need to use "[value](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#this-value)" field. But it is deprecated.